# How to add buffer to a video output? Video source is from private camera that has many filtering/lagging

Tags: python, opencv, count, webcam

Is there any way to add buffer so that the frame only collect enough image per second from a camera source? Because as of now, the video output is lagging so bad.

The code is running well and doesn't crash but it will lag until the screen no longer moves.

Is adding a buffer easier or is it possible to bypass the lagging/hanging made from the actual video source?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Resolution Pixel Size
# 640 x 480 - Standard Definition(SD)
# 1280 x 720 - High Definition(HD)
# 1920 x 1080 - Ultra High Definiion(HD+)
# 3840 x 2160 - Ultra High Definition(UHD or 2K)

cyanColor = (255, 255, 0)
pinkColor = (255, 0, 255)
yellowColor = (0, 255, 255)
greenColor = (0, 255, 0)
blueColor = (255, 0, 0)
redColor = (0,0,255)

path_vid = "Resources/video/license_plate.mp4"
path_main_ent = 'rtsp://~~~/Streaming/Channels/101'
path_parking_Lot = 'rtsp://~~~/Streaming/Channels/101'


button_person = False
button_car = False
button_truck = False

counter = 0
nmsThreshold = 0.3
confThreshold = 0.4

def rescale_frame(image, percentage):
    width = int(image.shape[1] * percentage / 100)
    height = int(image.shape[0] * percentage / 100)
    new_frame = (width, height)
    return cv2.resize(image, new_frame, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

def click_button(event,x,y,flags,params):
    global button_person
    global button_car
    global button_truck

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        print(x,y)

        #   ------  Person Button Clicking  ---------
        polygon_person = np.array([[(20, 160), (200, 160), (200, 230), (20, 230)]])
        is_inside_person_button = cv2.pointPolygonTest(polygon_person,(x,y),False)
        if is_inside_person_button>0:
            print("YAYYYY, We're clicking inside Button!!",x,y)

            if button_person is False:
                button_person = True
            else:
                button_person = False

            print("Now Person Button is: ",button_person)

        #   ------  Car Button Clicking  ---------
        polygon_car = np.array([[(20, 250), (200, 250), (200, 320), (20, 320)]])
        is_inside_car_button = cv2.pointPolygonTest(polygon_car, (x, y), False)
        if is_inside_car_button > 0:
            print("YAYYYY, We're clicking inside Button!!", x, y)

            if button_car is False:
                button_car = True
            else:
                button_car = False

            print("Now Car Button is: ", button_car)

        #   ------  Truck Button Clicking  ---------
        polygon_truck = np.array([[(20, 340), (200, 340), (200, 410), (20, 410)]])
        is_inside_truck_button = cv2.pointPolygonTest(polygon_truck, (x, y), False)
        if is_inside_truck_button > 0:
            print("YAYYYY, We're clicking inside Button!!", x, y)

            if button_truck is False:
                button_truck = True
            else:
                button_truck = False

            print("Now Truck Button is: ", button_truck)

# net = cv2.dnn.readNet("dnn_model/yolov3.weights", "dnn_model/yolov3.cfg")
# net = cv2.dnn.readNet("dnn_model/yolov3-spp.weights", "dnn_model/yolov3-spp.cfg")
# net = cv2.dnn.readNet("dnn_model/yolov3-tiny.weights", "dnn_model/yolov3-tiny.cfg")
# net = cv2.dnn.readNet("dnn_model/yolov4.weights", "dnn_model/yolov4.cfg")
net = cv2.dnn.readNet("dnn_model/yolov4-tiny.weights", "dnn_model/yolov4-tiny.cfg")

model = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(net)
model.setInputParams(size=(640,480), scale=1/255)

classes = []
with open("dnn_model/classes.txt","r") as file_object:
    for class_name in file_object.readlines():
        class_name = class_name.strip()
        classes.append(class_name)

# print("- Object List -")
# print(classes[0])

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path_main_ent)
# cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path_parking_Lot)

cv2.namedWindow("Frame")    # The name should be same with cv2.imshow("_Name_")
cv2.setMouseCallback("Frame",click_button)

while True:
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    # print(type(frame))
    if not ret:
        continue

    img_frame_90 = rescale_frame(frame, 90)

    line_frame_above = cv2.line(img_frame_90, (190, 430), (1220, 470), yellowColor, 2)
    line_frame = cv2.line(img_frame_90, (180, 440), (1220, 480), blueColor, 4)
    line_frame_bottom = cv2.line(img_frame_90, (170, 450), (1220, 490), yellowColor, 2)

    polygon_person = np.array([[(20, 160), (200, 160), (200, 230), (20, 230)]])
    cv2.fillPoly(img_frame_90, polygon_person, greenColor)
    cv2.putText(img_frame_90, "Person", (50, 200), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, blueColor, 2)

    polygon_car = np.array([[(20, 250), (200, 250), (200, 320), (20, 320)]])
    cv2.fillPoly(img_frame_90, polygon_car, greenColor)
    cv2.putText(img_frame_90, "Car", (50, 290), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, blueColor, 2)

    polygon_truck = np.array([[(20, 340), (200, 340), (200, 410), (20, 410)]])
    cv2.fillPoly(img_frame_90, polygon_truck, greenColor)
    cv2.putText(img_frame_90, "Truck", (50, 380), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, blueColor, 2)

    # polygon_truck = np.array([[(20, 430), (200, 430), (200, 500), (20, 500)]])
    # cv2.fillPoly(img_frame_90, polygon_truck, greenColor)
    # cv2.putText(img_frame_90, "Bus", (50, 470), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, blueColor, 2)

    (class_ids, scores, bboxes) = model.detect(img_frame_90,nmsThreshold=nmsThreshold, confThreshold=confThreshold)

    if len(class_ids) != 0:
        for class_id, score, bbox in zip(class_ids,scores,bboxes):
            (x,y,w,h) = bbox
            class_name = classes[class_id]
            xmid = int((x + (x + w)) / 2)
            ymid = int((y + (y + h)) / 2)

            if class_name == "person" and button_person is True:
                cv2.rectangle(img_frame_90, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), pinkColor, 2)
                cv2.circle(img_frame_90, (xmid, ymid), 3, redColor, -1)
                # cv2.putText(img_frame_90,str(class_name),(x,y-10),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,yellowColor,2)
                if ymid > 431 and ymid < 500 and xmid > 170 and xmid <1220:
                    line_frame = cv2.line(img_frame_90, (350, 440), (1220, 480), greenColor, 4)
                    counter += 1

            if class_name == "car" and button_car is True:
                cv2.rectangle(img_frame_90, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), greenColor, 2)
                cv2.circle(img_frame_90, (xmid, ymid), 3, redColor, -1)
                # cv2.putText(img_frame_90,str(class_name),(x,y-10),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,yellowColor,2)
                if ymid > 431 and ymid < 507:
                    line_frame = cv2.line(img_frame_90, (350, 440), (1220, 480), greenColor, 4)
                    counter += 1

            if class_name == "truck" and button_truck is True:
                cv2.rectangle(img_frame_90, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), cyanColor, 2)
                cv2.circle(img_frame_90, (xmid, ymid), 3, redColor, -1)
                # cv2.putText(img_frame_90,str(class_name),(x,y-10),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,yellowColor,2)
                if ymid > 431 and ymid < 507:
                    line_frame = cv2.line(img_frame_90, (350, 440), (1220, 480), greenColor, 4)
                    counter += 1

    cv2.putText(img_frame_90, 'Total Vehicles : {}'.format(counter), (0, 100), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, yellowColor,2)

    cv2.imshow("Frame",img_frame_90)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: please review [mre]. you have posted 175 lines of code. that is unlikely to be reproducible code.

Comment: Your code is working not lagging. I am not getting button on screen.

Answer (score 1):

Add this class and change few lines of your code. This will use the latest frame.

**Your code:**

```
while True:
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    # print(type(frame))
    if not ret:
        continue
```

**New code:**

```
cam = CameraBufferCleanerThread(cap)
while True:
    frame = cam.last_frame
    if frame is None:
        continue
```

**Example Code:**

```
from threading import Thread
import cv2

class CameraBufferCleanerThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, camera, name='camera-buffer-cleaner-thread'):
        self.camera = camera
        self.last_frame = None
        super(CameraBufferCleanerThread, self).__init__(name=name)
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            ret, self.last_frame = self.camera.read()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture("your/camera/url")
    cam = CameraBufferCleanerThread(cap)
    while True:
        frame = cam.last_frame
        if frame is None:
            continue
        else:
            cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: that's gonna spin through the main loop, at ~1000 loops a second, because waitKey(1) will not delay much, and there's no logic to wait for a fresh frame... -- instead you could use this https://gist.github.com/crackwitz/15c3910f243a42dcd9d4a40fcdb24e40